# Trying to Cross Sheet Copy and Paste into a single sheet, with different ranges of information

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Sheet that allows for a part number to be selected and all the Operations it goes through is pulled up, every Operations' steps are on different sheets.  What I'm trying to create is based on what operations it pulls up all operations procedures into one sheet to print.  Not all operations have same number of steps and not every part has the same number of operations.

The code I have works for the first operation, and the first 3 rows of the second operation.  But I can't get it to pull all of the sheet. Below is the code I'm using.  At the moment I'm only focused on OP 1 and 2 once I get that it has to be able to go 16 different Ops out of about 30 choices.

```
Dim rng As Range

If Sheets("Selection").Range("D3").Text = "N/A" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set rng = Sheets(Sheets("Selection").Range("D3").Text).Range("A12:" & ActiveSheet.Range("S12").End(xlDown).Address)
    With rng
        .Copy
    End With
    With Sheets("Print FMEA").Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -18)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

End If

If Sheets("Selection").Range("D4").Text = "N/A" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set rng = Sheets(Sheets("Selection").Range("D4").Text).Range("A12:" & ActiveSheet.Range("S12").End(xlDown).Address)
    With rng
        .Copy
    End With
    With Sheets("Print FMEA").Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -18)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unsure of your intention but guessing you want a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's deal with the errors first:

This line will throw an error `Sheets("Print FMEA").Row (Lastrow + 1)`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it, but the syntax is incorrect. I'm slightly surprised you say the code has worked for you.

This line will only select data to the next blank cell `Set rng = Sheets(Sheets("Selection").Range("D4").Text).Range("A12:" & ActiveSheet.Range("S12").End(xlDown).Address)`. You're probably only getting the first three rows because the fourth has a blank.

To answer your question, I think you need to think of this problem in two parts:

1. Store the reference details of each operation.
2. Loop through each operation and process the details.

There are many ways you could do this, but a `Class` object would work well. I've given an example which doesn't make optimum use of a class, but it does distinguish the two tasks.

So for part 1, insert a new class (*Insert ~> Class Module*) and name it OpsFields. Insert the following code which stores the sheet and cell references:

```
Private mSourceSheet As Worksheet
Private mRefSheet As Worksheet
Private mRefFirstRange As Range

Public Sub SetRefSheetAddress(sourceSheet As String, cellAddress As String)
    Dim sheetName As String

    Set mSourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sourceSheet)
    sheetName = mSourceSheet.Range(cellAddress)
    Set mRefSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
End Sub

Public Sub SetFirstRefAddress(columnsAddress As String, firstRow As Long)
    Set mRefFirstRange = Intersect(mRefSheet.Columns(columnsAddress), _
                         mRefSheet.Rows(firstRow).EntireRow)
End Sub

Public Function GetDataRange()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long

    r = mRefSheet.Rows.Count
    c = mRefFirstRange.Columns(1).Column
    lastRow = mRefSheet.Cells(r, c).End(xlUp).Row
    rowCount = lastRow - mRefFirstRange.Rows(1).Row + 1
    Set GetDataRange = mRefFirstRange.Resize(rowCount)
End Function
```

You then populate these classes and store them into some kind of list - I've used a `Collection` as you don't have to redimension it, so the number of operations doesn't matter. In the code below, I've given you an example of two but you could add as many as you want. This code would be in your `Module`:

```
Private mOpsList As Collection 'at top of module



Sub CreateOpsFields()
    Dim ops As OpsFields

    Set mOpsList = New Collection

    Set ops = New OpsFields
    ops.SetRefSheetAddress "Selection", "D3"
    ops.SetFirstRefAddress "A:S", 12
    mOpsList.Add ops

    Set ops = New OpsFields
    ops.SetRefSheetAddress "Selection", "D4"
    ops.SetFirstRefAddress "A:S", 12
    mOpsList.Add ops

End Sub
```

As for part 2, you simply loop through your list of classes and perform the paste task, as follows (again in your `Module`):

```
Sub RecordOps()
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ops As OpsFields
    Dim data As Range
    Dim nextBlankRow As Long

    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print FMEA")
    nextBlankRow = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each ops In mOpsList
        Set data = ops.GetDataRange
        data.Copy
        With outputSheet.Cells(nextBlankRow, "A").Resize(data.Rows.Count, data.Columns.Count)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
        nextBlankRow = nextBlankRow + data.Rows.Count
    Next
End Sub
```

You call these routines in the normal way. An obvious way would be to populate the classes in some kind of *Initialisation* routine and then call the paste routine when some event is triggered. I've just put both calls in one routine so you can see the syntax:

```
Sub RunMe()
    CreateOpsFields
    RecordOps
End Sub
```